# gitlab-runner build directory location does not respect the LaunchAgent (macos)

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have set up the toy multijob as shown in the [DAG pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/pipeline_architectures.html). I have updated my LaunchAgent plist to point to a specific build directory: /Users/me/Documents/GitLabCI/. The first job in the multijob runs in this directory. The rest of the jobs *always* build in /Users/me/.

How do I get gitlab-runner to respect the build directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LaunchAgent is no longer respected by gitlab-runner. Instead you have to do the following:

1. Add a `variables: GIT_CLONE_PATH = $CI_BUILDS_DIR` to your .gitlab-ci.yml file;
2. Add a value `builds_dir = "path/to/build/dir"` under the `[[runners]]` section in your config.toml.
3. Stop & restart gitlab-runner.